# What is REST ful API and how to use it in JavaScript

Tags: rest

I am learning Angularjs and i have gone through few application which are using heavily JSON data.

I come to know somewhere REST api provides data, so i want to understand what are REST api and how to use it or is these free?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of what REST is. It should not be characterized as a means to provide data or a piece of software that may not be free. REST is also not tied, in any way, to a specific programming language. A REST service may be consumed by a wide variety of languages, including JavaScript.

**So, what is REST?**

**REST - REpresentational State Transfer** is an *architectural style*!

REST is not tied to a specific protocol, however HTTP has become quite popular with REST.

The popularity of REST using HTTP is partly due to its very lightweight nature and the very natural mapping that exists between HTTP methods and CRUD operations. For example, when creating a RESTful API using HTTP, you can *loosely* think of your CRUD (Create, Retrieve, Update, Delete) operations as being the HTTP `POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, and `DELETE` methods respectively.

More importantly, **REST** also has some very nice *characteristics*:

- Everything is a Resource!!
- Resources expose a standard interface e.g. `POST`, `GET`, `DELETE`, `PUT` when used with HTTP
  REST operations (depending on the op) carry special characteristics e.g. safe, idempotent, and/or cacheable (see this [post](http://carminedimascio.com/2013/09/restful-design-principles/) for details)
- Resources are linked
- Multiple representations e.g. XML, JSON, RDF
- Communication is stateless

See this [blog post](http://carminedimascio.com/2013/09/restful-design-principles/) on [REST Design Principals](http://carminedimascio.com/2013/09/restful-design-principle) for more details on REST and the above stated bullets.

Answer (score 0):

Rest api in general is used to get or save data from or to the database or other source. rest is light and hence is beter than soap in regard to performance. Using json with rest is easy and a good option as it directly converts object to json and vice versa.
@consumes and @produces are useful in this context.